# Is it permissible to ask for help from social services and press charges against a husband who badly abuses his wife for no reason?

Tags: husband-wife, violence

If a husband is excessively beating his wife and abusing her mentally, sexually, emotionally and physically, this is clearly a case of domestic violence.

Is it permissible to press charges and get help from police forces, etc?

Comment: Absolutely. What kind of question is this? If someone is being assaulted, authorities should be contacted. I hope you weren't thinking that Islam forbids contacting authorities? That's nonsensical.

Comment: Of course it is!

Comment: Obviously. By the may what even makes you think this won't be permissible.?